# Bulk data load job not visible for bulk upload

Tags: integration, data-loader, data, bulk-api, upsert

An external system uses the bulk api to push bulk data into Salesforce. THis external system will only push the data if Salesforce sends a request to push the data. I beleive all the bulk data that is uploaded through bulk api or dataloader or dataloader CLI or any other means will appear in Bulk data load jobs( correct me if I am wrong here). However recently in my org few 1000's of records where updated but I do not see anything in the bulk data load job list. I am unable to find out how these data were updated into salesforce from nowhere. The user who updated appears to be the credential which is used by external system to push data in Salesforce but it does not happen without we request for data to be pushed and even if it happens without requesting, it should show up in Bulk data load job list. Any insights?

Reference - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=monitoring_async_api_jobs.htm&type=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies there has been a mistake. I suspect there was a bulk job which ran but was not present in bulk job list because the jobs are retained only for last 7 days. may be this job was deleted and it's been over 7 days.

Comment: makes sense​‌​‌​‌​

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessarily true that all data that is uploaded through the dataloader or dataloader CLI will use the bulk api.

There is a CLI process configuration parameter called `sfdc.useBulkApi` that needs to be set to true in order for these actions to appear in the Bulk data load jobs. The dataloader gui based tools have similar settings to toggle making these actions through the SOAP or bulk api.

[Data Loader Guide](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/6/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_data_loader.pdf)

Comment: Are you saying the job will appear in bulk data load only if bulk API is selected in dataloader?

Comment: I did test with BULK api not enabled in Data Loader but the job appeared in bulk data job list

Comment: My guess would be that even though you didn't explicitly choose to use the bulk api, the data loader must have decided to use it anyways.

Comment: I tested it with only 2 records. You guess might be right if there are large amount of data. Correct me if I am wrong